# Adding single IP addresses from different /64 IPv6 blocks in CentOS 7

Tags: ip, linux-networking, centos7, ipv6

I've got a /48 block which I'm trying to break up and use on a single server. I need to add 5 IPv6 addresses but they must all be in different /64 subnets.

Lets assume my /48 is 2001:ab10:f100::

I've tried to add the addresses using the following:

```
ip -6 addr add 2001:ab10:f100:1000:1000::/64 dev eth0
ip -6 addr add 2001:ab10:f100:2000:1000::/64 dev eth0
ip -6 addr add 2001:ab10:f100:3000:1000::/64 dev eth0
ip -6 addr add 2001:ab10:f100:4000:1000::/64 dev eth0
ip -6 addr add 2001:ab10:f100:5000:1000::/64 dev eth0
```

However - I can't ping out to IPv6 sites doing after this. Also, when I reboot the IPs are gone.

I'm using CentOS 7.

Is there something else I should be doing?

Comment: Adding IPs using IP command adds it temporarily. Here is the tutorial shows how to add IP permanently. You will have to add gateway as well to make those IP work properly. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-additional-ipv6-addresses-to-your-droplet

Comment: All I have is an IP and a DUID. Can I get the gateway from either of these?

Comment: Usually, gateway is the last Ip address of IP block. You can try adding 255 at the end of ipv6 address and see if works. Your provider should pass this info to you along with the IP block